# ¿Como arreglo este error que me sale al abrir mi aplicación hecha en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, app, google-play

He hecho una app en android studio y me funcionaba. Probé a exportar el apk para probarla y funcionaba. Hasta ahí todo bien.

Luego al subirla a PlayStore, la instalo y cuando intento abrirla no puedo y me salta un error que lo adjunto en una captura.

La parte de código de la aplicación que creo que da error es esta:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

}
```

¿Alguna idea de como arreglarlo? El error que sale al abrir la app en el móvil después de instalarla esta adjunta como captura.

[image: Eror que sale al intentar abrirla la app]

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer un debug de la aplicación dentro de Android Studio para que puedas saber con exactitud en dónde está el error.

Comment: Ya hice debug pero no me salen fallos, solo me pone "execution completed"

Comment: Ya hice debug pero no me salen fallos, solo me pone "execution completed". Es que el código que puse arriba de dependencies en realidad es lo de importar librerías, que creo que puede estar el error en las librerías. Cuando exporto el apk funciona pero al subir la app a PlayStore, la instalo y luego no me deja abrirla y me salta el error que adjunte en la captura.

Comment: Como meto la librería "libstatic-webp.so" en /system/lib.
Y como meto la librería "libnativeloader.so" en /system/lib64